# OR in logistice regression opposite

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to find the Odd Ratio of a DV (ability to function independently) with post covid. The descriptive table shows that non-indpendent patients have a higher percentage of covid:

```
     
       Independent Not independent
   Yes          72              37
   No          345              58
```

However, when I run the logisitic regression, the OR is in the opposite direction (OR=0.327):

```
logistic= glm(post_covid_dic ~  function_dependent_dic, 
+               family = binomial, data= subsetted_data_for_regression)
> summary(logistic)

Call:
glm(formula = post_covid_dic ~ function_dependent_dic, family = binomial, 
    data = subsetted_data_for_regression)

  Deviance Residuals: 
      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
  -1.8743   0.6157   0.6157   0.6157   0.9934  

  Coefficients:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                             1.5669     0.1296  12.093  < 2e-16 ***
function_dependent_dicNot independent  -1.1174     0.2471  -4.522 6.13e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 530.19  on 511  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 510.73  on 510  degrees of freedom
  (660 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 514.73

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> exp(cbind(OR= coef(logistic), confint(logistic)))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                                             OR     2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)                           4.7916667 3.7419167 6.2231095
function_dependent_dicNot independent 0.3271445 0.2018723 0.5329792
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Obviously _post_covid_dic_ has values "yes" "no", which might evaluate to 2 and 1 (alphabetical), try `I(post_covid_dic == "Yes") ~ function_dependent_dic` as formula.

Comment: The model you have is equivalent to the model you want.  It's just that the OR (and it's CI etc) are reciprocals of what you were expecting.  Inference from the two models will be identical.  It's slightly concerning that you have a missing data rate of over 50%.

Comment: Thanks! I reveresed the level of the DV (using relevel) and the results are now correct. There are a lot of missing because these participants don't have the DV. BTW, what is "I" in R?

Comment: The use of `I` in R is very nicely explained if you type `?I` into your console. In a formula it is used to indicate that mathematical operators inside the `I()` are used as mathematical operators rather than as formula operators.